# Map feature not working on Home Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento version 1.7.0.2 and I set MAP feature in my site.
MAP feature work perfectly in category listing and product detail page but in home page its give me js error.

`Reference Error: Catalog is not defined`

Anybody know how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

ok. After some research I got the solution.
To make MAP pop-up work on the home page, add these code in **local.xml** of your theme:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <update handle="MAP_popup" />
 </cms_index_index>
```

It should be added somewhere between `<layout>` and `</layout>.`